# Proving that Möbius transformation maps real axis to real axis iff real coefficients

Tags: complex-analysis, proof-verification, mobius-transformation

I'm trying to prove the following:

Show that a Möbius transformation T maps the x-axis to itself if and only if T can be written $$T(z)=\frac{az+b}{cz+d}$$ where the constants $a,b,c,d\in\Bbb{R}$.

---

I have found the following proof, but I am confused/not convinced by it (in particular the iff-part). Perhaps you can convince me or provide a correct proof. My confusion lies in the lack of justification for $cz+d$ in the denominator.

1) Assume that $T(\infty)=\infty$. Then, $T(z)=\frac{az+b}{c}=a'z+b'$.

$T(0)\in\Bbb{R} \implies b'\in\Bbb{R}$

$T(1)\in\Bbb{R} \implies a'+b'\in\Bbb{R}$

So $a',b'\in\Bbb{R}$.

2) Assume the contrary, $T(\infty)=e\in\Bbb{R}$.

Let $s(w)=\frac{1}{w-e}$ and $u(z)=S\circ T$. Then, $u(\infty)=\infty$ so $u$ can be written with real coefficients according to (1). Therefore, $T=S^{-1}\circ U$ can also be written with real coefficients.

---

I apologize for my poor formatting, this is my first time on this site.

Comment: Do you mean you want to know why $T(z) = \frac{az+b}{c}$ when $T(\infty) = \infty$?

Comment: No, I think I understand that part. I don't see why $T$ must be written with $cz+d$ in the denominator (specifically the $cz$ part.) Sorry for not being able to express myself more clearly.

Comment: A Mobius tranformation is by definition of that form.

Comment: @JohnMa Would what I am trying to prove not be true for $c=0$?

Comment: For $c = 0$, the proof is actually $(1)$ (Unforunately the $c$ there in (1) is actually the $d$ in the expression $cz+d$ (ie the case $c = 0$). While (2) deal with the case $c\neq 0$.

Comment: I think I get it now, thank you! Would you say my inability to understand the proof is purely because of my inexperience or is the proof also not very well-presented?

Comment: I would say that the proof is a bit rough.

Answer (score 3):

Suppose $T(z) = \frac{az+b}{cz+d}$, just by plugging in $z=0$ and $z=\infty$ we see that $\frac{b}{d}$ and $\frac{a}{c}$ are reals. Then plug in $z=\frac{a}{c}$ we see

$$T(\frac{a}{c})= \frac{a^2/c +b}{a+d}= \frac{a^2/cd + b/d}{a/d +1}\in \mathbb{R}$$
Simple manipulation shows that $\frac{a}{d}$ is also real, thus $\frac{b}{c}$ and $\frac{d}{c}$ are reals. Now

$$T(z)=\frac{az+b}{cz+d}= \frac{ \frac{a}{c}z + \frac{b}{c}}{z+\frac{d}{c}}$$ with coefficients being reals.