# Find all Mobius transforms that preserve the real and imaginary axes

Tags: complex-analysis, mobius-transformation

I need to find all Mobius transforms $f(z)=\frac{Az+B}{Cz+D},\text{ } A,B,C,D \in \mathbb{C}$ which map real numbers to real numbers and imaginary numbers to imaginary numbers. That is if $z \in \mathbb{R}$ then $f(z) \in \mathbb{R}$ and if $z \in i\mathbb{R}$ then $f(z) \in i\mathbb{R}$.

So far, I have considered the case where $f(i) = -i$ and $f(1)=-1$. The first of these expressions results in the conditions that $A=-D,B=C$ while the second results in $B=0$, hence $f(z) = -z$ as expected. But I am not sure how to generalize this.

Comment: What have you tried? We prefer you show work that you've done because A) knowing the sticking point can help with helping you understand the problem and B) it shows you're not just looking for us to do your homework for you.

Comment: @eyeballfrog Well intuitively if $A=K,B=0,C=0,D=L$ where $K,L \in \mathbb{R}$, then this is a mobius transform which maps all points on the axes to points also on the same axes. I am not sure how to prove that this is the only form the Mobius transform which fixes axes can take. I have tried

Comment: You should put everything you just commented in the question body.

Comment: Well, one reason you can't prove that is that it's not true. There's also the ones that are real multiples of $1/z$. I don't think there are any more.

Comment: I have taken the liberty to replace “fix” by “preserve” in the title. “Fixing the real axis” usually means that $f(x) = x$ for all $x \in \Bbb R$, that is not what you meant.

Comment: Connected : https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1491591/305862

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a possible strategy:

- $0$ lies both on the real and on the imaginary axis, therefore $f(0)$ is either $0$ or $\infty$.
- Show that $f(\infty)$ is also either $0$ or $\infty$.

So there are exactly two possibilities:

1. $f(0) = 0$ and $f(\infty) = \infty$, or
2. $f(0) = \infty$ and $f(\infty) = 0$.

Finally show that $f(z) = Az$ in the first case, and $f(z) = A/z$ in the second case, with $A \ne 0$.

*Remark:* Here, in the context of Möbius transformations, I have assumed that $f$ preserves the “extended real axis” $\Bbb R \cup \{ \infty \}$ and the “extended imaginary axis.” With the more strict assumption that $f(\Bbb R) \subset \Bbb R$ and $f(i\Bbb R) \subset i\Bbb R$ only the first case is possible, i.e. $f$ is linear.